# Is there a protocol for android which allows direct file modifications from computer?

Tags: file-transfer, file-management

Both the MTP and PTP protocols for file transfer do not allow editing or viewing files on  the phone from computer directly. In other words, you have first copy the file from the phone on the computer and then view/edit it. Are there any alternate protocol that support viewing/editing files directly?